# to_json introduces strange character

Tags: ruby

With this code I implemented a tree

```
groups = {"al1o0"=>"A1", "al2o2"=>"A10", "al2o3"=>"A11", "al1o1"=>"A2"}

map = {}
arr = []

groups.each_with_index do |group, index|
  level = (group.first.split("o")[0].split("al")[1]).to_i - 1
  level = level == 0 ? nil : level
   order = group.first.split("o")[1]
   arr.append({ :id=> index + 1, :order => order, :name => group.last, :parent => level})
end

root = {:id => 0, :name => '', :order => 0, :parent => nil}

arr.each do |e|
  map[e[:id]] = e
end

tree = {}

arr.each do |e|
  pid = e[:parent]
  if pid == nil
    (tree[root] ||= []) << e
  else
    (tree[map[pid]] ||= []) << e
  end
end
```

tree has

```
 => {{:id=>0, :name=>"", :order=>0, :parent=>nil}=>[{:id=>1, :order=>"0", :name=>"A1", :parent=>nil}, {:id=>4, :order=>"1", :name=>"A2", :parent=>nil}], {:id=>1, :order=>"0", :name=>"A1", :parent=>nil}=>[{:id=>2, :order=>"2", :name=>"A10", :parent=>1}, {:id=>3, :order=>"3", :name=>"A11", :parent=>1}]}
```

Up to here all right but If I do tree.to_json, the output is

```
 => "{\"{:id=\\u003e0, :name=\\u003e\\\"\\\", :order=\\u003e0, :parent=\\u003enil}\":[{\"id\":1,\"order\":\"0\",\"name\":\"A1\",\"parent\":null},{\"id\":4,\"order\":\"1\",\"name\":\"A2\",\"parent\":null}],\"{:id=\\u003e1, :order=\\u003e\\\"0\\\", :name=\\u003e\\\"A1\\\", :parent=\\u003enil}\":[{\"id\":2,\"order\":\"2\",\"name\":\"A10\",\"parent\":1},{\"id\":3,\"order\":\"3\",\"name\":\"A11\",\"parent\":1}]}"
```

Why It changed :id=>0 in :id=\u003e0?

Comment: `\u003e` is the `>` sign. You get it because of `=>`

Comment: To add a reference with Stefans comment: https://unicode-table.com/en/003E/

Comment: Keep in mind that in JSON [**an object key must always be a string**](https://json.org/) for this reason *to_s* is called upon the keys you provided (`{:id=>0, :name=>"", :order=>0, :parent=>nil}` and others).

Comment: Show your expected result, I'm pretty sure that your `tree` structure isn't right.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in 2.5 I get `"{\"{:id=>0, :name=>\\\"\\\", :order=>0, :parent=>nil}\":[{\"id\":1,\"order\":\"0\",\"name\":\"A1\",\"parent\":null},{\"id\":4,\"order\":\"1\",\"name\":\"A2\",\"parent\":null}],\"{:id=>1, :order=>\\\"0\\\", :name=>\\\"A1\\\", :parent=>nil}\":[{\"id\":2,\"order\":\"2\",\"name\":\"A10\",\"parent\":1},{\"id\":3,\"order\":\"3\",\"name\":\"A11\",\"parent\":1}]}"` @JohanWentholt while you are correct `Hash#to_s` just  wraps the whole hash as a string eg. `{h:12}.to_s #=> "{:h => 12}"`. Seems like there is an encoding issue that is not divulged in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all tree looks weird.

`{{:id=>0, :name=>"", :order=>0, :parent=>nil}=>[{:id=>1, :order=>"0", :name=>"A1", :parent=>nil}, ...]}}`

here is a key
{:id=>0, :name=>"", :order=>0, :parent=>nil}

and
[{:id=>1, :order=>"0", :name=>"A1", :parent=>nil}, ...]
is a value.

Key should not be a hash. How to call it later then.

You might need something like

{"A1" =>  {name: 'foo', order: '0' }, 'A2' => ...}